# How do you call a built in sqlite function from a custom sqlite extension function?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to call time('now') in my custom sqlite extension function. time() is a standard sqlite function.  I have included a sample extension function below.

```
#include <sqlite3ext.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1

/*
** The gettime() SQL function returns the current time.
*/
static void timeFunc(sqlite3_context *context,int argc,sqlite3_value **argv){

  sqlite3_result_text(context, time("now"),strlen(time("now")),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}
/* SQLite invokes this routine once when it loads the extension.
** Create new functions, collating sequences, and virtual table
** modules here.  This is usually the only exported symbol in
** the shared library.sdaffsd
*/
int sqlite3_extension_init(sqlite3 *db,char **pzErrMsg,const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi){
  SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi)
  sqlite3_create_function(db, "gettime", 1, SQLITE_UTF8, 0, timeFunc, NULL, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the SQL query `SELECT time('now')`.

Comment: I rather directly call the time function instead of executing a SQL query.

Comment: An SQL function requires SQL.